# Channel Entries pagination - breaking into an embed file

Tags: channel-entries, pagination

I would like to break out my pagination code into a separate embed file as the same code is used in multiple templates. However when I do it's just spitting out EE tags into the page rather than parsing them.

Is this a parse order issue? Is it possible to achieve this?

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="events" 
    orderby="date" 
    sort="desc"  
    paginate="bottom"
    disable="category_fields|member_data|relationships"
    limit="5"
    dynamic="no"
  }

  <div class="card card-horizontal clearfix event-list 
    {if segment_2 == 'weekly'}hidden-xs-up{/if}" 
    {if segment_2 == 'weekly'}data-day="#{event_start_date  format='%D'}"{/if}
    >
    <div id="events-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    {event_images cover_only="yes"}     
      <a href="/iba-kids/events/{url_title}">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{image:url:medium}" alt="{image:title}">
      </a>
    {/event_images}
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">{title}</h4>
      <p class="card-text">{exp:power_truncate length="110" cut_words="n" suffix="..."}{event_snippet}{/exp:power_truncate}</p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary category" href="/iba-kids/events/{url_title}">Read Article</a>      
    </div>
  </div> 

  {embed="inc/_paginate-full"}

  {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Embed Code:

```
        {paginate}
        <nav>
        {pagination_links}
          <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
            {first_page}
            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="page-link" href="{pagination_url}" aria-label="First Page">First</a>
            </li>
            {/first_page}
            {page}
            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="page-link {if current_page}active{/if}" href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a>
            </li>
            {/page}
            {last_page}
            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="page-link" href="{pagination_url}" aria-label="Last Page">Last</a>
            </li>
            {/last_page}
          </ul>
        {/pagination_links}

        {pagination_links}
          <ul class="pagination pagination-lg pull-xs-right">
          {previous_page}
            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="page-link" href="{pagination_url}" aria-label="Previous">Previous</a>
            </li>
          {/previous_page}
          {next_page}
            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="page-link" href="{pagination_url}" aria-label="Next">Next</a>
            </li>
          {/next_page}
          </ul>
        {/pagination_links}
        </nav>
      {/paginate}
```

Comment: can you provide an example of your channel entries loop with the embed?

Comment: Hey Jim, just added the code to the post. Thanks

Comment: You need to use a snippet instead for the pagination code, as an embed is parsed completely separately and after the parent template is parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely a parse order issue http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf
Embeds are processed after module tags.